# Updating and refreshing front end variables with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am wanting the item quantity my Cart page to refresh and update if quantity is changed with out having to refresh the page. The buttons are working regarding adding and removing items to the back end. But nothing is happening on the Cart page its self.

**My view:**

```
def get_item_quantity(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(user=user)
            quantities = {item.product_id: item.quantity for item in cart.items.all()}
            return JsonResponse({'quantities': quantities})
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': 'Cart not found'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': 'User not authenticated'})
```

**My scripts:**

```
function updateCartItem(cartId, cartItemId, quantityToAdd, csrftoken) {
    fetch(`/api/carts/${cartId}/items/${cartItemId}/`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        quantity: quantityToAdd,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Cart successfully updated:", data);
        updateCartQuantity();
        updateItemQuantity();
      });
  }

  function updateItemQuantity() {
    fetch("/get_item_quantity/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.status === 'error') {
          console.error(data.message);
        } else {
          document.getElementById("item-quantity")
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
  
  window.addEventListener("load", updateItemQuantity);
```

**HTML SNIPPET {{item.quantity}} is what i want to be updated:**

```
{% for item in items %}          

<svg class="icon--cart update-cart" data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="add">
            <use href="/media/sprite.svg#plus-solid"/>
</svg>

     <span id="item-quantity{{item.product.id}}" class="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</span>

<svg class="icon--cart update-cart" data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="remove">
            <use href="/media/sprite.svg#minus-solid"/>
</svg>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("item-quantity")` doesn't do anything

Comment: Ok, I changed that, still not working

Comment: Looks like the id of those spans is made from the string "item-quantity" plus the item id value.

Comment: <span id="item-quantity">{{item.quantity}}</span> This also doesnt work.

Comment: Yea because an id value should only appear on the page once. The old way of giving the elements unique id values was fine, but as posted your code did not make use of that form.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this advice... what do you suggest I do? I've been on this for days, although it may seem simple to some, im stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To break it down:

You have a pre-parsed JSON object (`data.quantities`) that you want to loop through, containing key (the ID) and value (the new amount) pairs.

In your else statement:

```
//loop through the key/value pairs
for (key in data.quantities) {
   //get the unique ID for the span to be updated by concatenating the product.id
   let span = document.getElementById("item-quantity" + key)
   //update the HTML text inside the element by getting the value associated with the key
   span.innerHTML = data.quantities[key]
}
```